# How to set webkit-transform programatically with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, webkit, webkit-transform

I am trying to set the transform3d attribute with jQuery. To do it, I am using the following function;

```
  setZIndexes(element, value) {
    $('#' + element + '').css({
      "-webkit-transform": 'translate3d(0, ' + (-this.offsetHeight) + ',' + value + 'px)',
      "-ms-transform": 'translate3d(0, ' + (-this.offsetHeight) + ',' + value + 'px)',
      "transform": 'translate3d(0, ' + (-this.offsetHeight) + ',' + value + 'px)',
    });
  }
```

Then, I am printing the values with the following function to see if it is changed or not;

```
 getZIndexes(el) {
    var results = $(el).css('-webkit-transform').match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(\d+(?:, \d+)*(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+)), \d+\)|\(\d+(?:, \d+)*(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+))\))/)

    if (!results) return [0, 0, 0];
    if (results[1] == '3d') return results.slice(2, 5);

    results.push(0);
    return results.slice(5, 8);
  }
```

However, it always returns to [0, 0, 0]

Comment: This line is really horrible: `var results = $(el).css('-webkit-transform').match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(\d+...` What you are trying for? Describe your problem and provide your html, if possible.

Comment: @WaldemarIce just forget that line. I just copied it to from somewhere to see if it is changing or not. Just focus on the first function. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use just unprefixed version. Prefixed are no longer necessary.